# Github static pages, the root of the URL

Tags: github, github-pages, static-site

I have a couple of GitHub pages and by default, GitHub groups them based on the URL of the user or organization, such as `<username>.github.io/<repository>`. However, I want to set up a master page that serves as the entry point on the root URL `<username>.github.io/` without including the repository name so I can refer from this root page to other projects.

I tried using the repository name as the username, `<username>.github.io/<username>` but it still resulted in a subdirectory `/username`. I couldn't find any mention of this feature in the documentation, is it even possible to achieve this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name the root repository like this "username.github.io" (not just "username"). More info: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-build-portfolio-website-and-host-it-on-github-pages/